# how to bind event on all elements except first 1 in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind `hover` event on all `.menu class` element except `first element` for this i wrote the following code :

```
        $(".menu:not(:first-child')").hover(function () {
        },
        function () {
        });
```

But this is not working. Whats the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".menu").not(":first-child")
```

or

```
$(".menu").not(":eq(0)")
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method

```
$('.menu').slice(1).hover(function () {
    // in
}, function () {
    // out
});​
```

*Just to be different...*

Comment: Not only different but also quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
$('.menu').not(":first")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".menu:not(:first)").hover(function() {

 },
 function () {
 });
```